# How to execute a stored procedure within a SELECT clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a scenario like this. I need to execute a stored procedure within a `SELECT` statement where the input parameters to the calling stored procedure are taken from the table being used in the `SELECT` statement. Also, there are multiple function calls as below which use the input from table used in `SELECT` clause but for some reason it doesn't work. Here is my code example as below which I am trying to implement.

Code Sample :-

```
SELECT A,
       B,
       dbo.storedproc( function1(A,B),
                       function1(A,B),
                       function2(B,C),
                       D
                      ) AS newcol,               
       D
 FROM Table;
```

Error :-

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Procedure XYZ, Line 34
>   Cannot find either column "schemaname" or the user-defined function or aggregate "schemaname.dbo.storedproc", or the name is ambiguous.

Note :- I am calling this stored proc for all the rows in the input table by using a set-based approach.

Comment: No, you cannot do this. It should be a scalar function or dynamic sql.

Comment: I have a very long chain of CTE's where in one of the CTE's I am trying to implement this functionality....

Answer (score 4):

you can't execute stored procedure in select..What you are looking for is a Scalar valued function/table valued function like below

```
--scalar valued function
    create function dbo.test( int a)
    returns int
    as
    begin
    return someval of int
    end
```

now you can call above in select like below

```
select a,b,dbo.test(a) from t
```

if your stored proc returns mutiple values ,you can create table valued function and can use cross/outer apply

---table valued function example

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ivf
     ( @a int,
       @b int )
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
        SELECT a,b from table
       )
```

Now you can call this like below

```
select a,b from table t1
cross apply
(select * from dbo.ivf(a,b))c
```